# Filling hashtable itinerating through it in c# and showing it in aTextBox

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, hashtable

i'm trying to fill a hashtable, the key is just a number ID and the content an array of intergers. I'm unable to show it in a TextBox and I think the problem comes from both the filling and the showing.

Filling code is:

```
        Hashtable map = new Hashtable();

        for (int cooX = 0, cont = 0 ; cooX < maxX; cooX++)
        {
            for (int cooY = 0; cooY < maxY; cooY++)
            {
                for (int cooZ = 0; cooZ < maxZ; cooZ++)
                {
                    coordinate[0] = 0 + cooX;
                    coordinate[1] = 0 + cooY;
                    coordinate[2] = 0 + cooZ;

                    map.Add(cont, coordinate);

                    cont++;
                }
            }
        }
```

And the showing part is:

```
        foreach ( DictionaryEntry i in map )
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();

            txt.AppendText(i.Key + " : " + i.Value);

            MainGrid.Children.Add(txt);
        }
```

TextBox shows:

"0 : System.Int32[]"

Thank you all.

Edit: Wow, that was incredible dumb by me, I've changed my code so it now effectively shows the Hashtable just by declaring the TextBox BEFORE the for and showing it AFTER it.

New code is:

```
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();

        foreach ( DictionaryEntry i in map )
        {
            txt.AppendText(i.Key + " : " + i.Value + "\n");
        }

        MainGrid.Children.Add(txt);
```

So it must be just a conversion problem. Going to look into it now, sorry for the big mistake.

New output is:

(...)
    3 : System.Int32[]
    2 : System.Int32[]
    1 : System.Int32[]
    0 : System.Int32[]

New code for loop, courtesy of msmolcic below, is:

```
foreach ( DictionaryEntry i in map )
{
int[] coords = (int[])i.Value;

txt.AppendText(string.Format("{0} : [ x={1}, y={2}, z={3} ]\n", i.Key, coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]));
}
```

And it displays as follows now, which is still broken:

```
4 : [ x=4, y=4, z=4 ]
3 : [ x=4, y=4, z=4 ]
2 : [ x=4, y=4, z=4 ]
1 : [ x=4, y=4, z=4 ]
0 : [ x=4, y=4, z=4 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same instance of coordinate for all the elements in your map. So in each iteration, you overwrite its content
You must create a new instance each time and it will fix your problem

EDIT

if you want to have a cleaner code, I suggest you to use a more OO oriented approach and define your own Coordinate class. You can then override the ToString method. If possible, you should also replace your Hashtable by a dictionary as this one is typed

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Coordinate>();
var count = 0;

for (var cooX = 0; cooX < 2; cooX++)
{
    for (var cooY = 0; cooY < 2; cooY++)
    {
        for (var cooZ = 0; cooZ < 2; cooZ++)
        {

            dict.Add(count++, new Coordinate { X = cooX, Y = cooY, Z = cooZ });
        }
    }
}

TextBox txt = new TextBox();
foreach (var i in dict)
{
    var coord = i.Value;
    txt.AppendText(string.Format("{0} : {1}\n", i.Key, coord));
}

MainGrid.Children.Add(txt);
```

Coordinate:

```
class Coordinate
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[ x={0}, y={1}, z={2} ]", X, Y, Z);
    }
}
```

if you are already on VS2015 you can also use string interpolation to replace string.Format with a more readable syntax:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[ x={X}, y={Y}, z={Z} ]";
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that was right, I was assigning the same overrided object everytime. I solved and I'll update the question. Thank you both, it's a real shame I can't select both your solutions because both of you fixed each problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the complete solution and a cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

sroll and msmolcic in this same thread has come with the right solution fixing, each of them, one of the problems. So, to keep it clean I'm going to post the final code here. If someone come with a better, cleaner, code for this, I'll select your answer as better solution:

```
        Hashtable map = new Hashtable();

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();

        int[] coordinate = new int[3];

        for (int cooX = 0, cont = 0; cooX < 2; cooX++)
        {
            for (int cooY = 0; cooY < 2; cooY++)
            {
                for (int cooZ = 0; cooZ < 2; cooZ++)
                {
                    coordinate[0] = 0 + cooX;
                    coordinate[1] = 0 + cooY;
                    coordinate[2] = 0 + cooZ;

                    int[] coo = new int[3] { coordinate[0], coordinate[1], coordinate[2] };

                    map.Add(cont, coo);

                    cont++;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (DictionaryEntry i in map)
        {
            int[] coords = (int[])i.Value;

            txt.AppendText(string.Format("{0} : [ x={1}, y={2}, z={3} ]\n", i.Key, coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]));
        }

        MainGrid.Children.Add(txt);
```